# uitable and invisible figures

Tags: matlab, printing, figure, invisible, matlab-uitable

The following code produces a plot and a table on an invisible figure.

```
 f = figure('Visible','off')
 plot(rand(10),rand(10))
 t = uitable('Parent',f,'Data',rand(10,10))
 saveas(f,'file.jpg','jpg')
```

The only problem is, that the table will not get printed/saved to a file, I have tried to use `print` as well to verify it. Neither does the order in which I put `plot` and `uitable` matter.

Is there a workaround for this? The reason why I want this to work is, that I would like to save hundreds of plots + table next to it to files and do not want to draw them, as it seems to take some time, although it is just plotting.

The following code will then show the figure, and after that the table magically appears on the print as well.

```
set(f,'Visible','on')
```

This is always reproducible so far, I am running R2011a.
Thanks :)

Comment: it seems to be working for me fine on R2010b. though I have to use `plot` instead of `Plot`.

Comment: YetAnotherUser has a point. Plot should be lowercase. R2011a, works after that correction.

Comment: I know that plot is lower case and it is a typo in the code. What I am looking for is saving a uitable and plot in a figure, whilst it is invisible, as soon as I make it visible it works, but that is not the desired outcome/way.

Answer (score 0):

That is a known bug : 
[A question I asked long time ago in Matlab Central forums](http://www.mathworks.it/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/251223)

Answer (score 0):

It is stated in the [PRINT](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/print.html#f30-463424) function documentation (which SAVEAS calls) that:

> If you print or export in nodisplay mode, none of the uicontrols the
>   figure has will be visible. If you run code that adds uicontrols to a
>   figure when the figure is invisible, the controls will not print until
>   the figure is made visible.

So it's not really a bug, more of a limitation...