# Matlab fitlm - plot mdl and display mdl in figure

Tags: matlab, plot, subplot

Using matlab's fitlm to make some linear models. As per the documentation I can get it to plot the model, and display the details of the model in the command window. Is there a way I can display both the model and the details in the same figure?

eg

```
%make the model
mdl = fitlm(X,comp);

%plot the mdl
subplot(1,2,1)
plot(mdl)

%Display the details
subplot(1,2,2)
%stuff that appears in command window here
```

Fitlm documentation: https://au.mathworks.com/help/stats/fitlm.html

Update - what I want to show in the subplot is "mdl.coefficients" which I can plot with

```
fig = uifigure;
uit = uitable(fig,"Data",mdl.Coefficients);
```

However I get this error when trying to put it in a subplot:

```
Error using uitable
Functionality not supported with figures created with the figure function. For more information, see Graphics Support in App
Designer.

Error in uitable (line 53)
        thandle = builtin('uitable', varargin{:});

Error in regressionmodelling_all (line 216)
    uit = uitable("Data",mdl.Coefficients);
```

So perhaps this is impossible? Functionality not supported?

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6074830/uitable-and-invisible-figures) suggests that `uit = uitable('parent',fig,'Data',mdl.Coefficients);` should work, even if the context is not exactly the same

Comment: @BillBokeey "unrecognised function or variable 'fig'" error :/

Comment: Should not be unrecognized if you define it before ..

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the axes, in this case the `subplot` axes, into the `plot` function for the LinearModel object, so

```
ax = subplot(1,2,1);
plot(mdl, ax);
```

And you can stick the command window output from the fit into an `annotation`. Since 2021a you can use [`formattedDisplayText`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/formatteddisplaytext.html) to capture the command window output which would come from `disp(mdl)`, so we have

```
str = formattedDisplayText( mdl, 'SuppressMarkup', true );
annotation( 'textbox', 'string', str, 'fontname', 'consolas', ...
    'Units', 'norm', 'position', [0.5,0.1,0.48,0.8], 'interp', 'none' );
```

If you don't have the Consolas font installed you can fall back on `'fontname', 'fixedwidth'`, or not use a fixed with font at all but your table won't be so neat.

If you're using MATLAB pre-2021a then you won't have the `formattedDisplayText()` function instead you can use:

```
str = evalc('feature(''hotlinks'', ''off'');disp(mdl)');
```

Output figure:

[image: plot]

Comment: Looks good but can you post the code as one thing - when copy paste this as ">> ax = subplot(1,2,1);
plot(mdl, ax);
>> str = formattedDisplayText( mdl, 'SuppressMarkup', true );
annotation( 'textbox', 'string', str, 'fontname', 'consolas', ...
    'Units', 'norm', 'position', [0.5,0.1,0.48,0.8], 'interp', 'none' );"  I get the error "Unrecognized function or variable 'formattedDisplayText'."

What have I done wrong?

Comment: @user2587726 Which version of MATLAB are you using? As I mention in the answer, that function was only available from 2021a onwards. I've edited my answer to include an alternative with `evalc`, so you would run the `ax=` and `plot` lines as before, then the `str=evalc` line, then the `annotation` line